# Drawing ASCII art using java

Tags: java

I have a problem to draw a square ASCII with the size limit in 20 character (size of 'square'), this is my code, I've tested and it works but when I put the number more than 20 it's display an error, pls help, thanks.

```
class Main {
    public static void printSquare(int size) {
        int line = 1;

        while (line <= size) { // For each line of square
            int width = size; // width of square segment
            int i = 1; // display square segment

            while (i <= width && size <= 20) {
                System.out.print("*");
                i = i + 1;
            }

            System.out.println(); // Newline
            line = line + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @MeenaO - checkout this Q&A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you'll never print the `*` if the size is greater than 20. A better way to restrict it to 20 would be to limit the size before the loop.

```
public static void printSquare(int size) {
    if(size > 20) {
       size = 20;
    }
    int line = 1;
```

and then edit

```
while (i <= width && size <= 20) {
```

to

```
while (i <= width) {
```

Comment: thanks, but what i mean is to display * to 0 when the value of size is greater than 20, so i modify them to:                          public static void printSquare( int size )
  {
    if ( size >= 20 && size >= 0) {
    size = 0;
    }
    int line = 1;

Comment: Okey. It was not clearly stated and thus my answer, next time try to provide a little more information :) And btw, you accept it as an answer by ticking the outline to the left of the answer.