# drawing ASCII art in java

Tags: java

hi i would like to draw a square with * as an outline and dot in the middle with size range 4 -20.

```
*****
*...*
*...*
*...*
*****
```

i'm having a trouble to make the height equal with the length.
this is my code, could you please help.. thanks

```
class Main
{
  public static void printSquare( int size )
  {
    if ( size >= 20 && size >= 4) 
    { size = 4; }

    int squareLenght = size;
    int i = 1; 
    int p = 1;

    if ( p <= size )
    {
       int t = 1;

       while ( t <= squareLenght  )
       {
        System.out.print( "*" );
        t = t + 1;
       }
    }
       System.out.println();           //  Newline
       i = i + 1;


    while ( i <= squareLenght )
    {

       int d = 1; 
       int s = 1;


       if ( s < squareLenght  );{
       System.out.print( "*" ); 
       s = s + 1;
       }

       while ( d < size-1  )
       {
        System.out.print( "." );
        d = d + 1;

       }


       System.out.println( "*" );
        i = i + 1;


    }

    if ( p <= size )
    {
       int t = 1;

       while ( t <= squareLenght  )
       {
        System.out.print( "*" );
        t = t + 1;
       }
    }

    System.out.println();           
       i = i + 1;

}
}
```

Comment: haven't looked at your code, but you *are* using a monospaced font?

Comment: Didn't you do the square part yesterday already?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing ASCII art using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940323/drawing-ascii-art-using-java)

Comment: This is an upgraded version of the yesterdays assignment. This time (s)he wants dots instead of asterix in the middle.

Comment: When you say "square", do you mean the same number of character cells, or the same actual size? Character cells are typically around twice as tall as wide...

Comment: @Tedil: it looks like he's printing on the console, so it will likely be whichever font the console uses. Mine uses mono-spaced, and I think most do (but could be wrong).

Comment: what i mean square is the same number of character cells

Comment: @user761497 read my last edit for 1 more thing I wanted to tell you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing 1 too many lines in the body (in between the borders) because of this line:

`while ( i <= squareLenght )`

It should be `while ( i < squareLenght)` **OR** `while ( i <= squareLenght - 1 )` since there should be 2 borders and `size - 2` rows in the middle that make up the height.

Also, this doesn't make any sense:

```
if ( size >= 20 && size >= 4) 
{ size = 4; }
```

Perhaps for the range you want:

```
if (size > 20) size = 20;
else if (size < 4) size = 4;
```

Anyway your code's a bit of a mess with unnecessary `if` statements and just the whole structure of things. `for` loops would also be a good idea where you have `while` loops with an initialization, a condition and a modifier/increment. I'm not going to change it for you because it sounds like homework.

Anyway if you wanted to neaten it up, think about the actual structure and pattern of what you're doing, because it's fairly simple:

- Print `size` amount of asterisks (`'*'`) and a new line (top border)
- Loop `size - 2` times: (if `size` is 5, there are 3 lines in between the borders, ie. `size - 2`)

  - Print `'*'`
  - Print `'.'` `size - 2` times
  - Print `'*'`
  - Print a new line
- Print `size` amount of asterisks (`'*'`) and a new line (bottom border)

**EDIT**: I know you've already marked the question as answered, but just wanted to suggest you have a function like `printRepeatedly(char c, int count)` to reduce the amount of loops that you're repeating (it'll just be a `for` loop and a print statement).

I just rewrote your code and I only required 11 lines of code in `printSquare`, plus the 2 in `printRepeatedly`). If you're going to repeat code you should nearly always use functions/methods instead.

Comment: 11 lines is really a lot to do such a simple thing ; )

Comment: @CedricMartin my point was that it's a lot less than what he has. And anyway it's 2 for the `size` range checking/modifying above, 2 for `printRepeatedly('*', ..)` + `println()`, 5 for `middleSize = size - 2;`, `for` loop, `print('*')`, `printRepeatedly('.', ..)`, `println("*")`, then 2 more to print the bottom border. You could make it less but that's the way I described the algorithm above, not to mention that it's unnecessary to do it in less.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the condition in one of your while-loops.

```
while ( i <= squareLenght )
```

Should be:

```
while ( i < squareLenght )
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a *lot* of code do what you want to do ; )

Without entering into a "code obfuscation" contest, there are several way to make this shorter.

Like this:

```
public static void printSquare( int size ) {
    final int n = Math.max( 4, Math.min(20, size) );
    for (int y = 0; y < n; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
            System.out.print( x == 0 || y == 0 || x == n - 1 || y == n - 1 ? "*" : "." );
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```